# Steady State: Exclusion of Term

Tags: kinetics

**Synopsis**

We are given a proposed mechanism for the condensation of $\ce{(CH_3)_2CO}$ as follows

First Step: $$\ce{(CH_3)_2CO + OH^- <=> CH_3C(O)CH_2^- + H_2O}$$
Second Step: $$\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^- + (CH_3)_2CO -> Product}$$

**Attempt and Question**

I assume $\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-}$ is in steady-state, and obtain subsequently that $$ k_1 \ce{[(CH_3)_2CO][OH^-]} = k_{-1}\ce{[CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][H_2O]} + k_2[\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][(CH_3)_2CO]}$$ since I'm assuming the rate of change of $\ce{[CH_3C(O)CH_2^-]}$ is $0$.

From here, in my original attempt, I factored out the $\ce{[CH_3C(O)CH_2^-]}$, solved for it, and plugged it in to my rate equation $$\ce{Rate = $k_2$ [CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][(CH_3)_2CO]}$$ to obtain $$\ce{Rate = \frac{$k_1k_2$ [(CH_3)_2CO]^2[OH^-]}{$k_{-1}$[H_2O] + $k_2$[(CH_3)_2CO]}}.$$ But looking at my solution, I realize I didn't eliminate the $\ce{H_2O}$ term. This is where my question lies. In the steady state approximation, do I assume $\ce{H_2O}$ is in steady state too and follow the same steps, substituting it into my equation for the concentration of $\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-}$? I tried that, but in doing so, I obtain $$\ce{$k_1$[(CH_3)_2CO][OH] = $k_{-1}$[CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][H_2O]}$$ and that $$\ce{[H_2O] = \frac{$k_1$[(CH_3)_2CO][OH^-]}{$k_{-1}$[CH_3C(O)CH_2^-]}}.$$Plugging that in to my equation for $\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-}$, I obtain something that seems absurd, mainly that $$k_1 \ce{[(CH_3)_2CO][OH^-]} = \ce{$k_1$[(CH_3)_2CO][OH^-]} + k_2[\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][(CH_3)_2CO]}.$$ This, being obviously wrong, led to great confusion. How do I deal with the $\ce{H_2O}$ term? I recognize it has no role in forming the products, but it does have a role in the rate of disappearance of $\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-}$, so I can't just throw it away right? If I can, why is that? What am I missing here? This is my first chemistry course in college, so if this is a stupid question or if it's already been asked, please just kindly point me to a helpful resource.

Comment: if $\ce{CH3C(O)CH_2^−}$ is in steady-state so we can write that $\ce{\frac{d[CH3C(O)CH_2^−]}{dt}=0}$

Comment: Yes. I'm aware. I know what our assumption is, but I'm asking about the $\ce{H_2O}$ term, and how it relates to our steady-state assumption.

Comment: I use the assumption in my development of the equation $ k_1 \ce{[(CH_3)_2CO][OH^-]} = k_{-1}\ce{[CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][H_2O]} + k_2[\ce{CH_3C(O)CH_2^-][(CH_3)_2CO]}$.

Comment: what data do you have in your exercise? I think you can reasonably consider the low water concentration if the reaction takes place in an organic medium

Comment: There is no data. The entire question is in the synopsis.